# For azure terraform I am unclear about the output command?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

Do not understand when the Output command is used in azure terraform?  Where is the output going?  Why do we need this output for?  We have multiple tf files in aws which I am converting to azure.  What type of information is outputted?

Without this output information what would happen?

Please provide examples.

Thank you

Comment: I have multiple tf files and a separate variable file.  As well as a main.tf outside of the directory with the tf files. 
the output command which is run after subnet creation command.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of questions, I'm not sure I can cover all this but I can deo give an example.

A good practice would be to build terraform modules, then use the output from these modules to pass along arguments to other modules consuming the same type of input.

The following is a "base module" that creates a resource group, a Vnet, couple of subnets (external and internal for example), NSG and binds the rules to the subnets

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main_rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location

  tags = {
    group    = var.resource_group_name
    Customer = var.tag_reference
    stack    = "resource group"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main_vnet" {
  name                = "${azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name}-primary-vnet"
  address_space       = ["${var.vnet_cidr}"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name

  tags = {
    group    = var.resource_group_name
    Customer = var.tag_reference
    stack    = "virtual network"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend_subnet" {
  name                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name}-backend-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main_vnet.name
  address_prefix       = var.backend_subnet_cidr
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql", "Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend_subnet" {
  name                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name}-frontend-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main_vnet.name
  address_prefix       = var.frontend_subnet_cidr
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "default_nsg" {
  name                = "${azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name

  security_rule {
    name                        = "appgwV1Exception"
    priority                    = 100
    direction                   = "Inbound"
    access                      = "Allow"
    protocol                    = "*"
    source_port_range           = "*"
    destination_port_range      = "65503-65534"
    source_address_prefix       = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix  = "*"
    description = "This is needed to allow helth check of backend server to pass according to official documentation"
  }

  security_rule {
    name                        = "appgwV2Exception"
    priority                    = 200
    direction                   = "Inbound"
    access                      = "Allow"
    protocol                    = "*"
    source_port_range           = "*"
    destination_port_range      = "65200-65535"
    source_address_prefix       = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix  = "*"
    description = "This is needed to allow helth check of backend server to pass according to official documentation"
  }

  security_rule {
    name                        = "Office"
    priority                    = 500
    direction                   = "Inbound"
    access                      = "Allow"
    protocol                    = "*"
    source_port_range           = "*"
    destination_port_range      = "443"
    source_address_prefix       = "1.2.3.4/32"
    destination_address_prefix  = "*"
    description                 = "Allow 443 access from the office"
  }


  tags = {
    group    = var.resource_group_name
    Customer = var.tag_reference
    stack    = "NSG"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg_to_backend" {
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.default_nsg.id
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.backend_subnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg_to_frontend" {
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.default_nsg.id
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.frontend_subnet.id
}


output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.name
}

output "vnet_name" {
  value = azurerm_virtual_network.main_vnet.name
}

output "vnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_virtual_network.main_vnet.id
}

output "backend_subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.backend_subnet.id
}

output "frontend_subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.frontend_subnet.id
}

output "nsg_id" {
  value = azurerm_network_security_group.default_nsg.id
}
```

Again the terraform best practice is to use an output file but I'll spare you that for now, see the outputs at the bottom of the file, now I have another module for creating a VM, so my main.tf if you will or the complete file might look a bit something like this:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.21"
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
}


module "base_infra" {
  source               = "../../base_infra"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  vnet_cidr            = var.vnet_cidr
  backend_subnet_cidr  = var.backend_subnet_cidr
  frontend_subnet_cidr = var.frontend_subnet_cidr
  tag_reference        = var.tag_reference
}

module "webapp_vm" {
  source               = "../../webapp"
  resource_group_name  = module.base_infra.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location
  vnet_cidr            = module.base_infra.main_vnet_id
  subnet_id            = module.base_infra.backend_subnet_id
  tag_reference        = var.tag_reference
  datadisk_size_gb     = "200"
  instance_count       = "1"
  instance_name_prefix = "${module.base_infra.resource_group_name}-webapp"
  vm_size              = var.vm_size
  vm_username          = var.vm_username
  vm_password          = module.webapp_vm_password.password_result
}
```

I did cut some corners in my answer, hope I gave you enough