# Azure terraform—Unclear about the format of variables used for parameters of a command

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

For example when I create a resource group I want to create a variable for it.  Is the format:   “${var.name)”?  How about location = “${var.location}”.   Please also provide documentation on how to format other parameters.

I also want to use the name parameter however there is a name for different resources to be created such as subnet, nic name, iaas name...    How is a name parameter variable formatted for different commands?  They cannot all var.name.

Comment: This is all explained in the Terraform documentation. Did you start by reading that?

Comment: Why is the format for the parameters is different? For example,for resource group (location = var.location), location = "${var.location}", or (location = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.location)?
Which is correct? I have looked a the parameters for different commands however they use the parameter's with different formats?  I document that I previously looked at only defined the parameters and do not always explain?

Comment: Why is the format for the parameters so different? For example,for a resource group (location = var.location), location = "${var.location}", or (location = azurerm_resource_group.main_rg.location)?
Which is correct? I have looked a the parameters for different commands however they use the parameter's with different formats?  I document that I previously looked at only defined the parameters and do not always explain?  I though variables were formated as "${XXXXXXX.test.name}" or "${XXXXXXX.test.id}" or "${var.test}".  Please explain what I am misunderstanding from the documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242199/for-azure-terraform-i-am-unclear-about-the-output-command     this where I got some of the examples and also noticed the variances in different commands for azure terraform

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation here https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html

You can use the below script to create a resource group, virtual network and subnet:

I have provided comments to help you understand better

The following works for latest version of Terraform 0.12.x

**main.tf**

```
variable "name" {
  default = "kimdav111"
}

variable "location" {
  default = "West US 2"
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = var.name //This will be populated with default value of variable "name" ie "kimdav111"
  location = var.location //This will be populated with default value of variable "location" ie "West US 2"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.name}-network" //The will become "kimdav111-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.main.name}" //This takes the value from the above resource "azurerm_virtual_network" and will be populated with "kimdav111-network"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}
```

Hope this makes it clear!